# Concatenate multiple RTF files using Ruby

Tags: ruby, concatenation, rtf

I have multiple rtf files in a folder.  I need to concatenate these into one rtf file using Ruby v1.9.3 on Windows.

This is what I have so far:

```
files_to_be_joined = Dir["*.rtf"]

File.open("Joined.rtf", "w") do |output_file|
  files_to_be_joined.each do |input_file|
    File.open(input_file) do |file|
      file.each { |line| output_file.puts line }
    end
  end
end
```

This works in a mechanical sense:  It puts all of the rtf files in the folder together.  When I open Joined.rtf in a text editor, I can see that it includes all of the rtf files in the folder.  But when I open Joined.rtf in MS Word, I can only see the first one.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "concatenate". I *think* you actually mean that you want the main content of each file to appear sequentially in a new file. RTF isn't plain text; you need to pull out just the content and insert each file's "real" content into either a new file or one of the existing file.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I want the main content of each file to appear in sequence in a new file.  I don't know how to pull out the "real" content of each file.